# How do I pass json file in boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-route53

How do I pass json file as an argument in boto3?

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('route53')
doc = open('policy.json', 'rb').read()

response = client.create_traffic_policy(
    Name = 'test2',
    Document = '?????',
    Comment = 'new traffic policy'
)
```

I want to pass a json file in the place of Document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the JSON library

```
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('route53')
doc = json.loads(open('cp.json', 'rb').read())

response = client.create_traffic_policy(
    Name = 'test2',
    Document = json.dumps(doc),
    Comment = 'new traffic policy'
)
```