# How do I create a resource based policy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

I need to create a resource based policy by following below link. So I have used boto3 to achieve this.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-configuring-cloudwatch-logs.html

Below is python script.

```
import boto3, json
from assume_role import credentials

if __name__ == "__main__":
    credentials = credentials("AssumeRoleSessionEBSEncryption")

iam = boto3.client(
        'iam',
        region_name='eu-central-1',
        aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
    )
my_managed_policy = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "mq.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/amazonmq/*"
        }
    ]
}
    response = iam.create_policy(
        PolicyName='MQPolicy',
        PolicyDocument=json.dumps(my_managed_policy)
    )
    print(response)
```

I get below error after execution of the script. Please suggest.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mq_iam_policy.py", line 32, in <module>
    PolicyDocument=json.dumps(my_managed_policy)
  File "/home/ec2-user/workspace/scripts/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/workspace/scripts/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/workspace/scripts/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/workspace/scripts/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.MalformedPolicyDocumentException: An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreatePolicy operation: Policy document should not specify a principal.
[
```

Final Answer :-

```
import boto3, json
import os
from assume_role import get_temporary_credentials

AWS_ACCOUNT_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCOUNT_ID']
AWS_ROLE = os.environ['AWS_ROLE']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    credentials = get_temporary_credentials("AssumeRoleSessionEBSEncryption")
    client = boto3.client(
        'logs',
        region_name='eu-central-1',
        aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
    )
    response = client.put_resource_policy(
        policyName='MQPolicy',
        policyDocument='{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": { "Service": "mq.amazonaws.com" }, "Action":[ "logs:CreateLogStream", "logs:PutLogEvents" ], "Resource" : "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/amazonmq/*" } ] }'
    )
    print(response)
```

Comment: `my_managed_policy` is already a dict type I think, so `json.dumps` isn't needed maybe?

Comment: @Lamanus I followed below link. https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/python/example_code/iam/create_policy.py

Comment: Your reference uses boto3.client not resource.

Comment: @Lamanus The error is still the same :(

Comment: Oh, the error says `Policy document should not specify a principal.` But you did.

Comment: @Lamanus Yes.. Because I need to add Principal in my policy

Comment: Please don’t use a title that’s just a list of tags and keywords … that’s what the *tags* are for! Instead, be descriptive.

Comment: @KonradRudolph OK..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you, you cannot use the principal for this case. See the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html).

In order to use the principal, the policy should be resource-based.

> Resource-based policies – You can attach resource-based policies to a resource within the service. Resource-based policies **include a Principal element** to specify which IAM identities can access that resource. For more information, see Identity-Based Policies and Resource-Based Policies.

However, MQ does not support the resource-based policy as mentioned in the document.

Comment: Thank You. How should I proceed further?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon MQ does not support resource based policy as documented in the following AWS article :

[Amazon MQ - Working with IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html#app_integration_svcs)

Also, as per AWS documentation for configuring resource based policy for Amazon MQ, use put_resource_policy operation of AWS CloudWatchLogs services.

References :

[Configure resource based policy for Amazon MQ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-configuring-cloudwatch-logs.html#configure-resource-based-policy)

[Boto3 documentation for CloudWatchLogs put_resource_policy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.put_resource_policy)

AWS CLI Example :

```
aws --region us-east-1 logs put-resource-policy --policy-name AmazonMQ-logs \
        --policy-document '{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { 
        "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": { "Service": "mq.amazonaws.com" }, 
        "Action":[ "logs:CreateLogStream", "logs:PutLogEvents" ],
        "Resource" : "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/amazonmq/*" } ] }'
```

Comment: I am still getting similar error after passing principals in array. Edited my question.

Comment: Updated the answer. Looks like Amazon MQ doesn't work with resource based policies.

Comment: Thank You. How should I proceed further?

Comment: @Kally, Updated the answer :-)

Comment: I have updated question with answer. Could you confirm the same?

Comment: @Kally, please change the resource to 'logs' instead of 'iam' while creating the client. Rest looks fine.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your answer :(

Comment: When you are creating the boto client, you are still using the service name as 'iam', the first argument. The function put_resource_policy is part of CloudWatchLog service, whice service name is 'logs'.Example :  client = boto3.client( 'logs', ... )

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked like a charm. Final question:- How can I pass `policyDocument` value from a file?

Comment: add the policy in a json file, then read it as string and pass the string to put_resource_policy function. You used my answer and accepted the other one, LoL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375885/how-do-i-pass-json-file-in-boto3. Sample example for passing json document.

Answer (score 0):

Here my dears...

Install the AWS CLI agent for Windows and configure your credentials https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-windows.html

Create a JSON file in **"C:\Users\YOUR-USER\"** containing your policy. For example: **C:\Users\YOUR-USER\policy.json**. You can simply copy this one here and paste into your .json file:

```
{"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": [{"Effect": "Allow","Principal": {"Service": "mq.amazonaws.com"},"Action":["logs:CreateLogStream","logs:PutLogEvents"],"Resource" : "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/amazonmq/*"}]}
```

Open your CMD and simply type:

```
aws --region eu-central-1 logs put-resource-policy --policy-name amazonmq_to_cloudwatch --policy-document file://policy.json
```

Well Done ! This will create a **AWS RESOURCE POLICY**, which sometimes is not possible to create in the IAM console.